# NUnit System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, nunit

I developed a small Windows Forms application that allows a user to convert between the different values of three temperature scales, Fahrenheit, Celcius and Kelvin.  Being a novice tester, I began dabbling with NUnit and I thought a good way to learn the framework would be to add some testing code to this program.  The class that handles the bulk of the work is :-

```
public static class TemperatureConverter
{
    public static ConversionFormula CelciusToFahrenheit = t => ((t * 1.8) + 32);

    public static ConversionFormula CelciusToKelvin = t => (t + 273);

    public static ConversionFormula FahrenheitToCelcius = t => ((t - 32) * 5/9);

    public static ConversionFormula FahrenheitToKelvin = t => (t + 459.67)/1.8;

    public static ConversionFormula KelvinToCelcius = t => (t - 273);

    public static ConversionFormula KelvinToFahrenheit = t => (t * 9/5 - 459.67);


    public static double ConvertTemperature(double temperatureValue, ConversionFormula conversionFormula)
    {           
        return conversionFormula(temperatureValue);
    }
}
```

I started off by simply testing individual temperature values were converting correctly.  Eventually this became tiring and involved a lot of repetitive code, so  rather than writing one test per value, I used NUnit’s ‘Range’ and ‘Values’ attribute so I could test in batches of ten.  An example test method is:-

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    private ConversionFormula _fahrenheitToCelcius;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _fahrenheitToCelcius = TemperatureConverter.FahrenheitToCelcius;
    }

    #region Fahrenheit To Celcius Positive Values

    [Test, Sequential]
    public void ConvertFahrenheitToCelciusRange_0_To_10_RoundedTo2DP([Range(0, 10, 1)]double temperature,
                [Values(-17.78, -17.22, -16.67, -16.11, -15.56, -15, -14.44, -13.89, -13.33, -12.78, -12.22)]double expected)
    {
        double actual = TemperatureConverter.ConvertTemperature(temperature, _fahrenheitToCelcius);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, 1);
    }
```

The range values are the temperatures to test, in this case, from 0 to 10.  The values attribute contains the expected result for each test.  I am using NUnit 2.6.2 and Resharper Test Runner.  I added almost identical test methods in the one class file that stepped up the temperature range in values of ten.  For example, the next test would be :-

```
[Test, Sequential]
    public void ConvertFahrenheitToCelciusRange_11_To_20_RoundedTo2DP([Range(11, 20, 1)]double temperature,
                [Values(-11.67, -11.11, -10.56, -10, -9.44, -8.89, -8.33, -7.78, -7.22, -6.67)]double expected)
    {
        double actual = TemperatureConverter.ConvertTemperature(temperature, _fahrenheitToCelcius);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, 1);
    }
```

After each test was added, I ran it to see if it passed and it did.  Eventually, I ended up testing through ranges 0 - 150, so I had a total of 15 test methods per class.  Now a problem occurs.  Both the Resharper test runner and the NUnit test runner randomly reports

> NUnit  System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

```
    System.OverflowException...

Server stack trace: 
   at NUnit.Framework.RangeAttribute..ctor(Int32 from, Int32 to, Int32 step)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeParameterInfo parameter, RuntimeType caType)
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.GetAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider member, Boolean inherit)
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.HasAttribute(ICustomAttributeProvider member, String attrName, Boolean inherit)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.ValueSourceProvider.HasDataFor(ParameterInfo parameter)
   at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.DataPointProviders.HasDataFor(ParameterInfo parameter)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.CombinatorialTestCaseProvider.HasTestCasesFor(MethodInfo method)
   at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.TestCaseProviders.HasTestCasesFor(MethodInfo method)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestCaseBuilder.BuildFrom(MethodInfo method, Test parentSuite)
   at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.TestCaseBuilderCollection.BuildFrom(MethodInfo method, Test suite)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.BuildTestCase(MethodInfo method, TestSuite suite)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.AddTestCases(Type fixtureType)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.BuildSingleFixture(Type type, Attribute attr)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.BuildFrom(Type type)
   at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.SuiteBuilderCollection.BuildFrom(Type type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestFixtureBuilder.BuildFrom(Type type)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.GetFixtures(Assembly assembly, String ns)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.RemoteTestAgent.AgentRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

No matter how many times I try to re-run the tests, I get the same error.  Not only that, all other test files in the assembly that were working perfectly fine, now report the same problem.  At first I assumed it was a problem with the values passed into the Values or Range attributes, but to put this to the test, I created a fresh new assembly, added a reference to NUnit and copied and pasted the tests from my original assembly, to the new one.  Hey presto, the tests all run fine.  Now If I make no changes to the test file in the new assembly and run the tests from time to time, eventually I am greeted with the same error.  Not only that, all other test classes break again also. The only way around this is to create a fresh assembly and copy and past the old test files across.  This is no good as they will eventually break again.  I am an NUnit newby, so if anyone has come across this error before or can understand what I might be doing wrong here, then your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the stack trace and the code for your ConvertTemperature method.

If you kill the resharper unit test processes, does the error go away on the next test?

Comment: Hi Nikhil.  Killing the process does not work.  Restarting Visual Studio does not work.  Further info you have requested is posted above.  Thanks.

Comment: What about the stack trace and all possible details of the `OverflowException`? It might give a hint about where the problem is.

Comment: Try wrapping the call to ConvertTemperature inside a try/catch, specifying a catch(OverflowException e) and see if you can debug to get more details.

Comment: Hello @JeppeStigNielsen  Stack trace posted above.  It doesn't appear to be my code that is throwing it.  Seems to be an NUnit issue??

Comment: btw, I would add that ConversionFormula is a delegate:-                   public delegate double ConversionFormula(double temperature);  Used as alternative to the Strategy pattern.  That seemed like overkill for this job.

Comment: So I duplicated your code above and ran with nUnit. All tests passed, multiple times through.

Comment: Thanks @mannish for that.  Good to know I am not imagining this!!  In my new test assembly this end they also run fine, but as I add more tests and keep trying eventually it goes kaboom.  I have a strange feeling it will be something really simple and I will kick myself.

Comment: There's source code for [`RangeAttribute` class](http://nunit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.5.10.11092plus-pdfsg-1/RangeAttribute_8cs_source.html) here. How can the constructor overload in question throw that exception? Are you sure you don't have a `[Range]` with wrong parameters? Note, maybe not the same version of NUnit.

Comment: Looking at that NUnit source, id concur it may be an invalid Range parameter.  I will trawl though my test data and see what I can spot.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It did appear to be an incorrect range value on one rogue test.  The perils of copy and pasting.  That said, I still don't understand why it affected every other test in the assembly.  Even the correct tests failed when run individually, that is until I corrected the error.  Thanks for your hep.

Answer (score 0):

Well When we are trying to do arithmetic, casting or conversion operation in checked context that time it defines Overflow Exception.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: When we try code with expected overflow exception in Checked block so as per the behavior it should not throw the exception. But it is throwing the error. What is the reason?